# SuggestionBuilder with BoolQueryBuilder in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, booleanquery

I am currently using BoolQueryBuilder to build a text search. I am having an issue with wrong spellings. When someone searches for a "chiar" instead of "chair" I have to show them some suggestions.

I have gone through the documentation and observed that the SuggestionBuilder is useful to get the suggestions.

Can I send all the requests in a single query, so that I can show the suggestions if the result is zero?

Comment: are you using the java high level rest client?

Comment: yes..I am using Java high-level rest client

Answer (score 0):

**No need to send different search terms ie `chair`, `chiar` to get suggestions, it's not efficient and performant and you don't know all the combinations which user might misspell.**

Instead, Use the [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) or [fuzziness param in the match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) itself, which can be used in the bool query.

Let me show you an example, using the match query with the fuzziness parameter.

### index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "product": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
  "product" : "chair"
}
```

### Search query with wrong term `chiar`

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "product" : {
                "query" : "chiar",
                "fuzziness" : "4" --> control it according to your application
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_fuzzy",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.23014566,
        "_source": {
          "product": "chair"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the input..But I only need the suggestions not the auto-corrected results

Comment: @sree, what do you mean by just suggestions?

Comment: Got it, can you explain this `Can I send all the requests in a single query , so that I can show the suggestions if the results are zero` in details, what do you mean by all the requests in which single query, please explain it using some example

Comment: Currently, We are sending a search query to get the results.let's say when we search with a chair. It will return the results matching with a chair. Now if I search with "chiar" as no matches it is returning zero results. When we have zero results I have to show the suggestion. For suggestions, we have to send another query with suggestion builder. I wanted to know is there any extra attribute to pass on the search query to get the suggestions in the first request.

Comment: @sree, Intresting, let me see if its possible, can you share your code for creating the suggest query and normal search query, so that I don't hv to write them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210214/discussion-between-sree-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).